# MySQL - Get only the recent previous record but not all previous record

Tags: mysql

I have this sample table:

```
id    room_id   gauge    date
1     1         10       2018-10-03
2     2         17       2018-10-03
3     1         16       2018-10-05
4     2         25       2018-10-05
```

I only wanted to get the recent ones which is the 2018-10-05 record to show it as my previous gauge. How will I do that?

My attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM sample)
```

Comment: Do you want to return all records having the most recent date?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM sample)
```

the date you were trying to catch is `GREATER THAN` the max Date on your field.
So that the result will not be shown because the max date is `2018-10-05`. meaning only the greater value will be retrieved.

Comment: You don't need `>=`, because no date in the table can possibly be _greater_ than the max date :-)

Comment: Just to be sure sir :D haha

Comment: Um...using `>=` is incorrect.  I edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your should be asserting that the date *equals* the most recent date in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM sample);
```

Comment: What the?, I didnt notice that. Will be marked correct answer, Thanks :)